# get average using partitionby

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am having the following data
[image]

here 1 id can have multiple sub_segment_1 (id = 2036013106) or 1 id can have 1 sub_segemnt_1 and multiple sub_segement_2 (id = 2035867480), irrespective of how many instance of sub_segemnt_1 or sub_segement_2 a id has, i want to derive the average per id so that the explosion in sales is addressed

what i would like to have is something like this - sales / count(id) - this will give average
[image]

i tried the following approach

```
df_u = df_u.withColumn("sales", F.avg("sales").over(Window.partitionBy("id")))
```

but this gives me wrong results

Comment: what results did you get? your code seems valid

Comment: i get lower numbers than expected, in some cases higher

Comment: Please share the actual outcome